# Exclude log traces while TEST execution of maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

My maven project executes maven-surefire-plugin v2.22.0 TEST while building the application. By default the log level of surefire execution is INFO, and this plugin uses [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory].

I don't want my build process to log these traces while executing : maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test)

Please could anyone help how to skip logging in this plugin execution?

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<version>2.22.0</version>
```

I have tried exclusions and verbose=false, but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Put a`log4j.properties` under `src/test/resources` with the following content:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```